# How to convert malformed list into a list of int in python

Tags: python, list, literals

Here is my list; an output from a database entered as string:

```
list_=(('[96, 71, 16, 81, 21, 56, 91]',),)
```

My goal is to convert it into a list of ints: `[96, 71, 16, 81, 21, 56, 91]`

My attempt:

```
import ast
print ast.literal_eval(list_[0][0])
```

The expected output

`Output:[96, 71, 16, 81, 21, 56, 91]`

However, the solution is not compatible with some of the output

`list_[0][0]`

results in an error: out of range.

Any suggestions on other possible methods to solving the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Show us the scenario that *doesn't* work, not the code that *does*

Comment: You need to know how the input is generated, possible values. Otherwise the problem is impossible to solve.

Comment: list_[0][0] specifies an element in a list of lists while you are creating a list of integers...?

Comment: yea, you guys are right, its a complex scenario that I'm still trying to figure out, but if I could only find other ways of converting the malformed list into a proper one, that would be fine.

Comment: but you haven't shown us what a malformed list looks like!

Comment: The malformed list is right there at the top.

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment @Tiger1, I didn't realize you *are* OP. If that's what a "malformed list" is, and `literal_eval` is working, then what's the question?

Comment: The question is, I'm looking for other ways to convert the malformed list into a proper list. Something that will fit into my overall algorithm

Comment: @Tiger1 **but what do you mean by malformed?** If you are getting an `IndexError` then your problem isn't with `ast`, which would throw `SyntaxError`s instead. What was the value of `list_` when you got that `IndexError`?

Comment: Malformed means its not a proper list, you cannot iterate over it's values, it was stored as a string in a database.

Comment: you don't need any other ways to convert a malformed list. you're trying to extract a "malformed list" that isn't there *in the first place*. You have yet to show us the `list_` that generated the error

Comment: @Tiger1 Data serialization as strings is not malformation. **What was the value of `list_` when you got that `IndexError`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import ast
print ast.literal_eval([y for x in list_ for y in x][0])
```

Comment: What if you have `('stringstringstring',)`? This will make a list of the characters in the string. OP is talking about `IndexError`s anyway.

Comment: Hi @hwatkins, thanks for your solution. It works fine, I'll try and see if it can fit into my overall algorithm.

Comment: yea,its a combination of strings. Its an index thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
while type(list_) is not str:
    try:
        list_ = list_[0]
    except IndexError:
        break
```

Now `list_` is the string you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
from numpy import fromstring
fromstring(list_[0][0][1:(len(list_[0][0])-1)], sep=',', dtype='int32').tolist()
```

Comment: Hi @CCP, thanks for the solution, but I think hwatkins method is in line with what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

And just for fun, a generic untangler

```
from collections import Iterable

def untangle(thing):
    stack = [thing]
    result = []
    while stack:
        current = stack.pop()
        if isinstance(current, basestring):
            if current[-1] == ']':
                current = current[1:-1]
            for x in current.strip().split(','):
                result.append(int(x.strip()))
        elif isinstance(current, Iterable):
            stack.extend(reversed(current))
        else:
            print "dont know what do do with", repr(current)
    return result

untangle((('[96, 71, 16, 81, 21, 56, 91]',),))
[96, 71, 16, 81, 21, 56, 91]
```

Comment: Hi @cmd, thanks for you suggestion, it works but may be too long.I'm looking for a one or two lines of code approach.

Comment: @Tiger1 I figured it would be more then you wanted.  I posted this to solve the problem for any nesting of input ;)